# django-rest-framework non orm-based filtering

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using DjangoRestApi and while it works like a charm with queryset (orm-based) views, I am struggling to make views that use different back-end to behave same way orm-based views are. Notably I want to add filters and have them cast and validated automatically.

Pseudo code below:

```
class NewsFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    category = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='category')
    limit = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='limit')
    page = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='page')


class NewsView(generics.APIView):
    filter_class = NewsFilter

    def get(self, request):
        filters = self.filter_class(??)  # not sure, what to put here

        payload = logic.get_business_news(**filters.data)  # same

        return Response(payload, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Any hint how to tackle problem will be appreciated.

Ultimate goal is to:

- user types something into url or sends via POST, django-rest intercepts relevant values, extracts them, casts them into correct type and return as a dictionary
- filters are displayed as they would if serializer was ORM based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function signature to any single filter is like

```
class MyFilter(django_filters.Filter):
    def filter(self,queryset,value):
        [...]
```

[The function signature to a FilterSet is:](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/85ba7c456044b320201d5f0e98675291363efea5/django_filters/filterset.py#L161)

```
def __init__(self, data=None, queryset=None, prefix=None, strict=None):
```

So, it looks like you pass in `request.GET` as `data` param and then pass in your queryset.

Comment: I have slightly edited original question to clarify what I am looking for, as this answer is a) very incomplete and b) I have this feeling that don't answer my question

Comment: Fundamentally, `FilterSet` operates on querysets.  Do you have a query set that you're filtering down?  If not, you can't use `FilterSet`.

Comment: I don't want to work with queryset as I don't use ORM, what I do want is to render form in /api/ endpoint so that developers and other non-so-techy guys could test/work with api without manually typing json payload and so on. I started to figured out that django-rest-framework is actually very limited framework, with only one workflow in mind. :/

Comment: Ah true.  It really is mostly a backend for talking with machines.  You would normally write your frontend as a javascript client.

Comment: I should add that DRF is only an addendum to Django.  You can use DRF side-by-side with Django in the same app.

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it's the best what can be done with DRF. To actually to obtain same functionality, DRF had t be extended heavily. I decided to just put some good docstrings and ask user to manually prepare payload for the request.